# How to store Vue.js component data in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js, vuedraggable

I'm building a link builder that lets people share multiple links from one link. At the moment I have several "cards" that users can put into their link template. For example, this allows them to have links to their music on Spotify (one card), or a link to their Youtube channel (another card).

I'm using VueDraggable to allow users to drag their cards into their template..

[image: Screenshot of user interface]

What I don't understand is, how should I store the cards components in the store so that they can be draggable? At the moment in my store I just have all of the cards as objects, as VueDraggable needs the data to be in 2 different lists..

```
export const state = () => ({
    chosenCards: [
    ],
    defaultCards: [
        {id: 1, text: 'Twitter',  font: 'Arial',  destination: 'https://twitter.com/home', design: {color: '#1DA1F2', 'background-color': 'white', padding: '5px', margin: '5px', 'border-width' : '2px', 'border-color': '#1DA1F2', 'font-weight' : 600, font: 'Arial'}},
        {id: 2, text: 'Spotify',  font: 'Arial',  destination: 'https://twitter.com/home', design: {color: '#1db954', 'background-color': 'white', padding: '5px', margin: '5px', 'border-width' : '2px', 'border-color': '#1db954', 'font-weight' : 600, font: 'Arial'}},
        {id: 3, text: 'Youtube',  font: 'Arial',  destination: 'https://twitter.com/home', design: {color: '#c4302b', 'background-color': 'white', padding: '5px', margin: '5px', 'border-width' : '2px', 'border-color': '#c4302b', 'font-weight' : 600, font: 'Arial'}},
    ],
})
```

So I don't actually use any card components I've made. I want to be able to design the cards as components instead of just objects in my store, and still have them be draggable. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: The components themself is just visual representation of your card objects. Just add all the necessary props to these objects to build your cards properly.

Comment: @Anatoly do you suggest that I don't actually use components? the thing I don't understand is how to save a component in my vuex store as a card

Comment: Use components to visualize and not to store. Imagine that your card compoent show a number that is chosen by a user. So to save and restore the state of that component you just need to store that number and a type/name of your component (in case you have different components for different kind of numbers).

Comment: @IsaacJoy Can you share the current implementation of your store and the component?